# Unable to integrate Cypress with testlink

Tags: automation, cypress, integrate, testlink

Is there any way to integrate Cypress test cases with Testlink?

I think of a situation where when running the test, it created the suite test and the case test and updated the status of the testLink to for example passed (if cypress has run the entire test successfully)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible to integrate Cypress with Testlink Because Testlink has its own API and you would need to write your own plugin to integrate it though.

This is the path to the api: /lib/api/rest/v2 and Here are all the Rest endpoints: https://github.com/TestLinkOpenSourceTRMS/testlink-code/blob/testlink_1_9/lib/api/rest/v2/tlRestApi.class.php

then do a GET on http://localhost:3000/lib/api/rest/v2/whoAmI Good Luck